# How to RollBack after Commit in Postgres?

Tags: c#, postgresql

How to RollBack after Commit in Postgres?

Comment: *RollBack after Commit* read it again and again until you get it (how this makes no sens)

Comment: just use the same transaction in both methods ... you can pass it by parameter

Comment: Is it possible if I will pass tran paramter in UpdateModel  then tran.Rollback will work (if any exception happens)?

Comment: Please use plain text (formatted as code) instead of an image of it (https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0Cs3.png

Answer (score 4):

The only way to undo a committed transaction is to restore a backup from before the commit.